# How to deinstall top panel or allow programs/windows to be ontop of that panel

Tags: uninstall, panel, top

As the title says.

The problem is my screen size is 1080p, and i need a program to run in 1080p in window mode, but the top panel is forcing the programwindow out of the screen how to fix that. or deinstall the top panel.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: what kind of DE are you using?

Comment: DE? Environment? Unity- standard environment

Answer (score 1):

I installed now the gnome-shell, and its a pretty good solution, now I only got the panel on the left screen, and on the right (dual monitor) is now no panel, also every window has it's own toolbar, idk know how it's actually called.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

but yet not the solution I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Many programs can be set to run fullscreen by pressing F11.

You can use ccsm (compiz config settings manager) to temporarily remove the top & side bars.

Install ccsm & put shortcuts to the program and ccsm on your desktop, then use ccsm to disable the unity desktop plugin and run the program fullscreen in windowed mode.

Use ccsm to re-enable the unity plugin when you are finished.

Not the perfect solution, but a workable workaround until you get a better answer.

Comment: thanks, not perfect but better than nothing. is there a way to get the function what the top panel has, into the windows... i don't like the idea of have one bar for all windows. what i mean is, every window in windows has its own bar "data, edit, view, options, help, etc"